# Function on data.table environment errors

Tags: r, data.table

Can anybody explain to me why `bar` doesn't work? Is this a bug in `data.table`?

```
Circles<-data.table(radius=1:10)

foo<-function(Circ){
  Circ[,diameter:=2*radius]
}
dput(x = foo,file = 'func.R')
bar<-dget(file = 'func.R')

foo(Circles)

bar(Circles)
```

It has something to do with the fact that the dget function sets the environment of the object it returns to something other than `.GlobalEnv`. There's an easy enough work around, but it'll drive a rookie like me nuts trying to figure out why it broke in the first place.

```
MyDGet<-function(file){
  temp<-dget(file=file)
  environment(temp)<-.GlobalEnv
  return(temp)
}

bar<-MyDGet(file = 'func.R')
```

Answer (score 9):

from `dput`:

> If x is a function the associated environment is stripped. Hence scoping information can be lost.

```
parent.env(environment(bar))
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

Both `foo(Circles)` and `bar(Circles)` result in `[.data.table` getting dispatched, but in the case `bar()`, looking at `traceback()`:

```
traceback()
# 6: stop("Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(\":=\").")
# 5: `:=`(diameter, 2 * radius)
# 4: `[.data.frame`(x, i, j)
# 3: `[.data.table`(Circ, , `:=`(diameter, 2 * radius)) at func.R#3
# 2: Circ[, `:=`(diameter, 2 * radius)] at func.R#3
# 1: bar(Circles)
```

As you can see `[.data.table` dispatches to `[.data.frame`. This happens because of this part within `[.data.table`:

```
if (!cedta()) {
  # Fix for #5070 (to do)
  Nargs = nargs() - (!missing(drop))
  ans = if (Nargs<3L) `[.data.frame`(x,i) # drop ignored anyway by DF[i]
  else if (missing(drop)) `[.data.frame`(x,i,j)
  else `[.data.frame`(x,i,j,drop)
  # added is.data.table(ans) check to fix bug #5069
  if (!missing(i) & is.data.table(ans)) setkey(ans,NULL) # See test 304
  return(ans)
}
```

Here `!cedta()` is `TRUE` in case of `bar()`. We can confirm this is a `cedta` issue by setting `options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)` and rerunning.  We then get:

```
# cedta decided 'base' wasn't data.table aware
```

So what does `cedta()` do?

Suppose you're using `data.table` objects, and also using a package that's not aware of `data.table` data structure. And let's say the package has a function called `funA`. And you're calling the function as follows:

```
funA(DT)
```

Now since the package isn't *data.table aware*, it could be using code as follows:

```
funA <- function(...) {
    ....
    tmp <- DT[, cols]
    ....
}
```

Here `DT[, cols]` would not work on a data.table properly due to some minor differences in data.table's defaults (by default `with = TRUE`). And for a data.table, we'd need `DT[, cols, with=FALSE]`.

For your code to work well, we've to identify that you're using a data.table object on a function from a package that doesn't know how to subset columns from a data.table (or in other words, not *data.table aware*).

And we do that by looking at the parent environment of the function and that gives the namespace of the package you're using (if you're using a package), and then we check if this package *imports*, or *depends* on data.table, or if it's one of the packages that we've whitelisted.

This case is special (or strange) because the function *you defined* has parent environment as `base`, and the namespace `base` isn't data.table aware.

Therefore this is not actually a bug.

`?dget` describes this as **not** a good way to transfer objects between R sessions (under `NOTE` section). `saveRDS` works fine and you can use it as an alternative (better) workaround:

```
saveRDS(foo, "func.RDS")
bar <-readRDS("func.RDS")
bar(Circles)  # works
```

Comment: I don't understand enough of the implications to decide whether or not my code should run or stop, but if it stops, shouldn't the message be more reflective of this?

Comment: Also, there's a weird misalignment here. If I hand type a function then it defaults to the `.GlobalEnv` but if I `dget` a file that has the exact same text that I just typed, the environment defaults to `base`. Again, I don't understand all the implications but that feels like a bug in R.

Comment: Your code should stop.  You're in a weird area where several things are happening that are all corner case-y.  Just use `saveRDS` and don't worry about it.  The `dput` mechanism should probably attempt to record the environment of the function, but it doesn't.  Instead you end up with random environment when you `dget`.  `saveRDS` does save the environment in limited circumstances (and warns when it can't).

Comment: I should also note that it should be possible to make the error message a bit more helpful (i.e. if `:=` detects it is outside `[.data.table`, it should check the call stack to see if there is a `[.data.table` call within it, though that has to be done with some care).

Comment: @Adam, made an edit to explain why we do things this way. Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for this great answer! I would perhaps add that to fix the issue for a package that uses data.table, it is not enough that data.table is either in the Imports or Depends fields in the DESCRIPTION, but also needs to be imported via the NAMESPACE.

This seems obvious, but if you are using using roxygen2 to generate the NAMESPACE automatically and do not specifically `Import data.table` in the tags (e.g. it does not occur to you to import subset method explicitly) your package has data.table in Imports, the `R CMD CHECK` passes and you still have this issue.