# Manipulate data.table objects within user defined function

Tags: r, scope, data.table

I'm trying to write functions that use `data.table` methods to add and edit columns by reference. However, the same code that work in the console does not work when called from within a function. Here is a simple examples:

```
> dt <- data.table(alpha = c("a","b","c"), numeric = 1:3)
> foo <- function(x) {
    print(is.data.table(x))
    x[,"uppercase":=toupper(alpha)]
}
```

When I call this function, I get the following error.

```
> test = foo(dt)
[1] TRUE
 Error in `:=`("uppercase", toupper(alpha)) : 
 Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are
 defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

Yet if I type the same code directly into the console, it works perfectly fine.

```
> dt[,"uppercase":=toupper(alpha)]
> dt
   alpha numeric uppercase
1:     a       1         A
2:     b       2         B
3:     c       3         C
```

I've scoured stackoverflow and the only clues I could find suggest that the function might be looking for `alpha` in a different environment or parent frame.

**EDIT:** More information to reproduce the error. The function is not within a package, but declared directly in the global environment. I didn't realize this before, but in order to reproduce the error I need to dump the function to a file, then load it. I've saved all of my personal functions via `dput` and load them into R with `dget`, so that's why I get this error often.

```
> dput(foo, "foo.R")
> foo <- dget("foo.R")
> foo(dt)
 Error in `:=` etc...
```

Comment: I don't see that error. Perhaps you need to upgrade to version 1.9.6 of the package, currently on CRAN. By the way, because `foo` modifies `dt`, you don't need to assign the result like `test = foo(dt)`; just do `foo(dt)` and you'll see that `dt` itself is changed.

Comment: is your function inside a package? if so be sure you have data.table imported in NAMESPACE

Comment: not inside a package, but loaded manually with `dget()` or with `source()`. Perhaps that has something to do with why my functions can't access `data.table` methods? @Frank you're right, I tend to forget that `:=` changes the `data.table` without need for assigning a new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a different flavor of the one described in the post [Function on data.table environment errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549690/function-on-data-table-environment-errors). It's not exactly a problem, just how `dget` is designed. But for those curious, this happens because `dget` assigns the object to parent environment `base`, and the namespace `base` isn't `data.table` aware.

> If x is a function the associated environment is stripped. Hence scoping information can be lost.

One workaround is to assign the function to the global enviornment:

`> environment(foo) <- .GlobalEnv`


But I think the best solution here is to use `saveRDS` to transfer R objects, which is what `?dget` recommends.